# AKS Pod can't be accessed by External IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, azure-aks

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: organization-deployment
  labels:
    app: organization
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: organization
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: organization
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: organization-container
        image: test.azurecr.io/organizationservice:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: guidesecret
      
# service type loadbalancer       
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: organization-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: organization
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 9080
```

Here is my deployment.yaml file for AKS but i am unable to access pod using external ip with the port 9080.

Can anyone suggest how to access the pod using external ip and anyone review my Deployment file if it's fine how to access pod using external ip?

[image: kubectl get svc]

[image: kubectl describe svc]

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Use `kubectl get svc organization-service` to check whether an external IP is correctly attached first. Provide more details that could support to answer the question.

Comment: @SahanGunathilaka




organization-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.217.243   20.86.199.83   9080:31151/TCP   9h

Comment: @HarshManvar Hmmm… can't reach this page 20.86.199.83 took too long to respond.

Comment: Did you check any firewall rules applied or not ? And service up and running ?

Comment: @HarshManvar Service is up and running and no firewall rules have been applied

Comment: @SahanGunathilaka it has been updated please check if you can help

Comment: What is the ip:port that you tried accessing? Did you try with `LoadBalancer Ingress` IP?

Comment: it was http://<External-IP>:9080 LoadBalancer Ingress IP @SahanGunathilaka

Comment: I can't see any possible errors in your resources. Please check whether you have enforced some network restrictions for the Loadbalancer of your cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Provided information seems to be not consistent. There is one service with `ClusterIP` type and the other one is `LoadBalancer` type. Better to recheck your deployments and services. Then provide valid details.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your deployment and from validation point of view, there is nothing wrong with your deployment. I have tried to open the pod with loadbalancer ip and port and it gave me error 20.86.199.83 took too long to respond. So I assume there is something wrong with your application. In order to troubleshoot it, try to open the application directly using kubectl port forward. If the page opens, there is some issue with service. Otherwise you have to check from application.
Check if application is running on port 9080.
Exec into application pod shell.

```
kubectl exec -it {pod-name} /bin/bash
netstat -tulpan | grep -i :9080
```

If the above command retuns true, means application is listening on port 9080.

Exit from pod shell and do kubectl port-forward and check if application page opens up in browser.

```
kubectl port-forward pods/{pod-name} 9080:9080
```

Open page localhost:9080

Answer (score 0):

It was because of Kestrel HTTP2 Protocol which is not supported by aks